# AndroidX NavigationUI with DrawerLayout, support-v4 required?

Tags: android, navigation, android-support-library, androidx, android-jetpack

I'm trying to setup a new sample app with AndroidX navigation. As I understand it, you should never mix old support libraries with androidx, but classes within androidx appear to use these support libraries themselves?

Concrete example, I want to use:

```
NavigationUI.navigateUp(androidx.navigation.NavController navController,
        android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout drawerLayout)
```

So this means that I can't use my `androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout`? When using `android.enableJetifier=true` it even prevents me from accessing `android.support.v4` classes at all.

What would be the correct approach here?

Comment: I just ran into this just now...